# How to add a border radius to a box shadow that lies within the width range of the element?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a box shadow to a button with a border radius but the shadow itself should lie below the button and within its width range.

I was able to get the rounded border shadow but when trying to position it within the elements width range the border radius effect was lost and instead I got only the shadow without the border radius.

```css
.but1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
  background-color: yellow;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0 25px 0px -10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0 25px 0px -10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0 25px 0px -10px;
}
```

```html
<button class="but1">
  Click me!
</button>
```

The example of what I got till now is  linked below.

[Sample output in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/satilog/kbq2snum/5/)

Comment: Question is not clear. Can you please explain what you exactly want?

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/Zw4QA/1/

Comment: You define `.but` style but use `.but1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your box-shadow is being cropped because of the negative spread (the last parameter in your box-shadow declaration)

If what you want is a rounded shadow the exact same width of the element, then setting spread to zero and taking 10px out of the vertical offset to compensate will do.

```css
.but1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0 15px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<button class="but1">
  Click me!
</button>
```

---

If what you want instead is a shadow that keeps the rounded borders but is shorter than the element width, you can draw a shorter pseudo-element positioned behind it, and apply the box-shadow to the pseudo-element

```css
.but1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position:relative;
}

.but1:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute; top:10px; bottom:10px; left:10px; right:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  z-index:-1;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0 15px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<button class="but1">
  Click me!
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks!! @Facundo Corradini The second suggestion gets me what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Add `0px` to the `box-shadow`

```css
.but1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 100px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 9px;
}
```

```html
<button class="but1">
    Click me!
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update Your Css Like this.

```css
.but1 {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    border:none;
    background-color:yellow;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
 
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 7px 8px 1px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 7px 8px 1px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 7px 8px 1px;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `:after` to achieve this, just an idea, you can play around with the css as wish.

Code:

```css
.but1{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    border:none;
    background-color:yellow;
    
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
   /* -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.8)  5px 20px 0px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.8)  5px 20px 0px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 3px 9px;*/

}

.but1:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 16px;
    width: 84%;
    bottom: 37px;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius:10px;
    transform: scale(.9); 
    box-shadow: -1px 20px 14px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

```html
<button class="but1">
    Click me!
</button>
```